# How to set FadeInImage placeholder proterty to have a custom size in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using [FadeInImage](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images) widget to load images from the internet in my app. I wanted my placeholder image to have a custom size but the problem is I'm using the BoxFit.cover in the widget and that property also applies to the placeholder.

Is there a way for me to check if the image is not yet ready/loaded so I can change the fit property of my widget?

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                          placeholder: 'assets/images/loading_ball.gif',
                          image: imageList[index],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
```